# How to load xml in cron job

Tags: php, mysql, xml, feedparser

I have a problem in running the cron job.

here are my code:

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load( 'http://www.all-news.in/feed' );

    $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "item" );

    mysql_connect('host','username','pass');
    mysql_select_db('dbname');

    $i=0;
    foreach( $items as $itemname )
    {
        // Here Business logic for Inserting the data
    }   

    echo $i.' Imported';
?>
```

When I run this file in browser, it works fine, but when the cron executed I have got the below error:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::load(http://www.all-news.in/feed) [<a href='domdocument.load'>domdocument.load</a>]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in <b>/home/content/98/7509598/html/amz/social-bookmark.in/cron_jobs/all_news.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::load() [<a href='domdocument.load'>domdocument.load</a>]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;http://www.all-news.in/feed&quot; in <b>/home/content/98/7509598/html/amz/social-bookmark.in/cron_jobs/all_news.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
0 Imported
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code out and I'm not getting any errors.  I modified it a bit to give me some more feedback:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'http://www.all-news.in/feed' );

$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "item" );
var_dump($items);
// mysql_connect('host','username','pass');
// mysql_select_db('dbname');

$i=0;
foreach( $items as $itemname )
{
    var_dump( $itemname ); $i++;
    // Here Business logic for Inserting the data
}   

echo $i.' Imported';
```

This gives me:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#2 (0) { } object(DOMElement)#3 (0) { } object(DOMElement)#5 (0) { } object(DOMElement)#3 (0) { } object(DOMElement)#5 (0) { } object(DOMElement)#3 (0) { } object(DOMElement)#5 (0) { } object(DOMElement)#3 (0) { } object(DOMElement)#5 (0) { } object(DOMElement)#3 (0) { } object(DOMElement)#5 (0) { } 10 Imported
```

If you're testing on a local environment (your laptop perhaps) then try restarting your web server.  Other than that I'm not sure what's wrong sorry.

Comment: Yes thanks, I have sorted out this. Problem was on hosting account. They were in maintainance mode when my cron job runs. Thats why I have got the error. Thanks a Lot for your time..